# A base is made of eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I feel I am missing a very elementary point. In Serre's book "Linear representation of groups" p12 he takes $ s \in G $ and define a base of a representation $ V $ consists of eigenvectors of $ p_s$ ($ p: G \to End(V) $ is the representation).

I don't understand why is it possible, because $ p_s $ doesn't have to be diagonalized (If you aren't familar with representation theory concepts, I'll say that the question is if we can find for a regular matrix $ A \in C^{n \times n} $ a basic of $ C^n $ consists eignvector of $ A $. I didn't omit the context, becuase maybe I missed some assumption or something).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\rho:G\rightarrow \text{End}(V)$ be a group morphism where $G$ is a finite group. Let $n$ be the order of the group $G$. Then $\rho(g)^n=\rho(g^n)=\rho(e_G)=Id_V$. Hence $\rho(g)$ is a root of the polynomial $X^n-1$. Hence the minimal polynomial of $\rho(g)$ divides $X^n-1$, but $X^n-1$ splits into distinct linear factors (over $\mathbb{C}$) with no repeated roots. Hence the eigenvalues are distinct and $\rho(g)$ is diagonalizable.

Edit: In fact, let $d$ be smallest natural number such that $\rho(g)^d-Id_V=0$. Then any eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $\rho(g)$ with eigenvector $v$ satisfies $(\lambda^d-1)v=0$. Thus eigenvalues of $\rho(g)$ are $d$-roots of unity.